# how to scan all decorators value at runtime in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have to collect all decorator value that appears in different place in my app as string and then saving them to database at runtime, i don't have to add them twice (in database and in code),

i have tried to do it but i could not figure out i use

`Reflector` api from nestjs as following

```
this.reflector.getAll<string>('access', context.getHandler())
```

but i could not get `context.getHandler()` during run time

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
   

  // Here is where i want to save

  await app.listen(3000);

}
bootstrap();
```

here is my decorator

```
@HashPermission('access_value')
```

Please assist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something like this, you'll either need to make use of something like [Nest's undocumented `DiscoveryService`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/core/discovery/discovery-service.ts) or a package like [`@golevelup/nestjs-discovery`](https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/tree/master/packages/discovery) which is a friendly wrapper around Nest's package. You can then make use of methods like `this.discoveryService.methodsAndControllerMethodsWithMetaAtKey` to get the classes and methods that have that metadata, then you can use the reflector class on each method to get the metadata value.

Comment: thanks for your answer, please can you write a blog article on how to create nestjs module as npm package from scratch (i mean that can be added as npm dependency), i think this approach we will make it usefully and promoting others to write more modules

Comment: You mean [like this one](https://dev.to/nestjs/publishing-nestjs-packages-with-npm-21fm)?

Comment: yeas like the one you create above